# spring-boot-starter-amqp will works between micro services?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am new to Spring amqp.
I have tried to send the messages by following: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

I am able to send the messages within the micro services.
But unable to send the messages to another micro services ? Is it expected ?

If I want to send the messages between the micro services which dependency I should follow ?

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one service you would send the message and in an other receive it. In the example you now have both in 1 project. In the sending service you have the RabbitTemplate and in the other service the Receiver with the SimpleMessageListenerContainer and MessageListenerAdapter beans. Make sure that the binding, queue and exchange configuration are the same and the services are both connected to the same RabbitMQ server.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its working as expected. Just one confirmation, in the sending service I didn't specified any configuration for RabbitTemplate. I specified only the rabbitmq connection parameters in the application.properties file. Is Spring Boot created the RabbitTemplate bean with these connection parameters automatically ? Please confirm.

Comment: Correct. You understand that Boot magic properly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-amqp and see `RabbitProperties` for the defaults: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitProperties.java

Comment: @ArtemBilan instead of creating container and listenerAdapter beans:

Bean
 MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(MyMessageListener receiver) {
  return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
 }
Here MyMessageListener is the listener class.
I just annotated the method with annotation as below:
RabbitListener(queues = "someQueue")

But now application is not able to send/receive messages. What is the wrong here. ?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something like this (figure taken from a recent [blog post](https://reflectoring.io/event-messaging-with-spring-boot-and-rabbitmq/) of mine, which also shows more detailed code examples):

[image: Event producer and consumers are loosely coupled since an exchange serves as intermediary.]

- Here, as an example, CRUD-Events like "customer.created" or "order.deleted" are considered
- Any microservice can act as an Event Producer and send events to an event exchange via `RabbitTemplate`, which is provided by Spring AMQP and can just be injected into any Spring Bean.
- A cluster of instances of the same microservice share a queue.
- The consuming microservices declare their queue and the binding between queue and event exchange by declaring `@Bean`s of type `Queue` and `Binding` with the same attributes.
- The binding defines which events will be received by each microservice cluster
- All microservices must share the same event exchange by declaring a `@Bean` of type `Exchange` with the same exchange name.

Comment: beautifully explained. Thanks.
How to deal with multiple exchanges, multiple queuesin the service ?

Comment: You just declare multiple `Queue`s and potentially `Exchange`s  and wire them together with multiple `Binding`s